Change my Forest figure
Question: How can I achieve figure 2 from figure 1 ?

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{
    calign to midchild or edge midpoint/.style={
        if={isodd(n_children())}{
            calign=child edge,
            calign primary child/.process={
                O+nw+n{n children}{(##1+1)/2}
            },
        }{
            calign=edge midpoint,
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    my fork/.style={
        %           grow=south, 
        calign to midchild or edge midpoint,
    },  
    for tree={forked edge, edge=->, draw,
        thick,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum size=20mm, 
        l sep=12mm,
        align=left,
        fork sep=5mm,
        fill=blue!10, my fork
    }
    [Quadrilateral, s sep=1.6cm
    [Kite]
    [Trapezium]
    [Parallelogram, s sep=1.6cm, 
    [Rhombus, s sep=0.3cm
    ]
    [Rectangle]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


When you reuse code, please always include a link. This makes it much easier for people helping you. Even if the code is mine and I recognise it, I often can't find it. (I suspect this is either mine or Sašo's simply because I don't know anybody else who uses the argument processor, but I still can't find it.)
You already have multiline nodes with align=left. To centre them, use align=center. Since the new node isn't part of the tree (since trees only allow single-parent children), the easiest way is to add the node at the end. To make this easier we name the nodes or, rather, we give them aliases. We could also use relative node names.
  delay={for tree={%
      split option={content}{\\}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
      alias/.register=temptoksa}},

This code splits every node's content at any line break and uses the first line as an alias for the node. This is delayed so the content is definitely available.
Then we can use the existing names to place the new node,
  \node (Square) [anchor=north,draw,rounded corners,thick,yshift=-\foresteoption{l sep},minimum width=20mm,minimum height=10mm] at (current bounding box.south -| Parallelogram.center) {Square};

and to draw the connecting edges (which seem non-arrowed, but can be styled however you need in the usual ways),
  \draw  (Square.north) edge (Rhombus.south)  -- (Rectangle.south);

Complete code:
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721821/ addaswyd o gwestiwn SandyM: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721820/ (addaswyd o ??)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{
  calign to midchild or edge midpoint/.style={
    if={isodd(n_children())}{
      calign=child edge,
      calign primary child/.process={
        O+nw+n{n children}{(##1+1)/2}
      },
    }{
      calign=edge midpoint,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  delay={for tree={%
      split option={content}{\\}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
      alias/.register=temptoksa}},
  my fork/.style={
    %           grow=south, 
    calign to midchild or edge midpoint,
  },  
  for tree={forked edge, edge=->, draw,
    thick,
    rounded corners, 
    minimum size=20mm, 
    l sep'=12mm,
    align=center,
    fork sep'=5mm,
    fill=blue!10,
    my fork
  }
  [Quadrilateral, s sep'=1.6cm
    [Kite\\in the sky]
    [Trapezium\\in the air]
    [Parallelogram\\in the mind, s sep'=1.6cm, 
      [Rhombus, s sep=0.3cm
      ]
      [Rectangle]
    ]
  ]
  \node (Square) [anchor=north,draw,rounded corners,thick,yshift=-\foresteoption{l sep},minimum width=20mm,minimum height=10mm] at (current bounding box.south -| Parallelogram.center) {Square};
  \draw  (Square.north) edge (Rhombus.south)  -- (Rectangle.south);
\end{forest}
\end{document}



Yes you are right. This codes are not mine. I will be careful next time.

Can you shade the color to last box?

@SandyM You can add whatever style you want into the node. Right now it has [anchor=north,draw,rounded corners,thick,yshift=-\foresteoption{l sep},minimum width=20mm,minimum height=10mm]  which seemed roughly what your target picture showed. If you want it to be drawn in red and filled with green, just add draw=red, fill=green. (Not recommended - I think blue would be much better, as you suggest, but you can do to it whatever you'd do to any other tikz node.)

Nice explanation (+1)!

@cfr I couldn't wrap the text inside the square.

@cfr Kindly help me with the above query.

@SandyM Well, there was only one word in your original question ;). But just add align=center and use \\  the same as in the forest nodes.

Thank you for reply. I did it. Once again, thanks a lot for helping me

@SandyM No problem. Forest questions are almost my favourite ;).
